# JavaScript Dropdown Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am just getting into front-end web development and to practice, I made a dropdown selector that allows for more styling than the regular `<select>` element.

Please let me know what I can improve on (examples are appreciated, but not necessarily needed). I am mainly looking at the JavaScript, but if I am structuring things poorly in the html or there are problems in the CSS, please let me know.

I also have the project on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/hexlan/pen/azepGg) if it is easier to see it in action.

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Selector Styling</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hex-selector-0.9.9.css">
    <style>
      .container {
        width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      } 
    </style>
  </head>   
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="hex-selector">
        <div class="hex-selection" tabindex="1">
          <span value="null">Select a Place</span>
        </div>
        <div class="hex-content">
          <ul class="hex-list">
            <li value="#">Afghanistan</li>
            <li value="#">Albania</li>
            <li value="#">Algeria</li>
            ...
            <li value="#">Zimbabwe</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hex-selector">
        <div class="hex-selection" tabindex="1">
          <span value="null">Select a Color</span>
        </div>
        <div class="hex-content">
          <ul class="hex-list">
            <li value="#">Red</li>
            <li value="#">Orange</li>
            <li value="#">Yellow</li>
            <li value="#">Green</li>
            <li value="#">Blue</li>
            <li value="#">Violet</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/hex-selector-0.9.9.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**:

```
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.hex-selector {
  position: relative;

  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 350px;

  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;

  background: #0099FF;
  border: 1px solid #3079ed;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(50,50,50,0.1);

  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
     -khtml-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
}

.hex-selection:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 50%;

  margin-top: -3px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;

  border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff transparent;

  content: "";
}

.hex-selector:hover,
.hex-selector.active { background: #005CE6; }

.hex-selector.active > .hex-content {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.hex-selection { padding: 10px; }
.hex-selection:focus { box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(50,50,250,0.5); }

.hex-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 110%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;

  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.hex-list {
  max-height: 250px;

  font-weight: normal;
  list-style: none;

  background: white;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.17);
  border-radius: inherit;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);

  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.hex-list > li {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;

  color: #8aa8bd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e8ea;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.hex-list > li.current { background: #f3f8f8; }
```

**Javascript**:

```
/*
 * Hexlan Selector Replacer v0.9.0
 * 
 * Author: Reyer Swengel
 * Date: 2015-4-16
 */

(function () {
  var CURRENT       = "current",
      SELECTED      = "selected",
      ACTIVE        = "active",
      HEX_SELECTOR  = ".hex-selector",
      HEX_SELECTION = ".hex-selection",
      HEX_LIST      = ".hex-list";

  var clickTarget  = false,
      mouseIgnore  = false,
      typingReset  = 0,
      searchString = "";


  /**
     * Used as a callback for mouse events, allows mouse selection to be overridden by key navigation
     * @params {jQuery} target - element to highlight in dropdown
     */
    var mouseSelection = function(target) {
        if(!mouseIgnore) {
            $(HEX_LIST+" > li.current").removeClass(CURRENT);
            target.addClass(CURRENT);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Positions the item either at the top or bottom of the dropdown through scrolling
     * @params {jQuery} target - item to position in the dropdown
     * @params {jQuery} position - either 'top' or 'bot' referencing where it should be positioned in the dropdown
     * @params {jQuery} container - The .hex-selector containing the target
     */
    var scrollTo = function(target, position, container) {
        var temp_hex_list = $(HEX_LIST, container);
        if     (position === "top")    { temp_hex_list.scrollTop(temp_hex_list.scrollTop() + target.position().top); }
        else if(position === "bot") { temp_hex_list.scrollTop(temp_hex_list.scrollTop() - temp_hex_list.height() + (target.height() + 1)*2 + target.position().top); }
    }

    /**
     * Removes .selected from previous element and adds it to target
     * If the dropdown is open, it also updates .current
     * @params {jQuery} target - Item to change to .selected
     * @params {jQuery} container - The .hex-selector containing the target
     */
    var selectItem = function(target, container) {
        if($("."+SELECTED, container).length) { $("."+SELECTED, container).removeClass(SELECTED); }
        target.addClass(SELECTED);
        $("span", container).text(target.text());
        $("span", container).attr("value", target.attr("value"));
        if(container.hasClass(ACTIVE)) { updateCurrent(target, container); }
    }

    /**
     * Toggles the dropdown for the target. Jumps to the selected element if exists
     * @params {jQuery} target - .hex-selector to toggle
     */
    var toggleSelector = function(target) {
        if(target.hasClass(ACTIVE)) {
            target.removeClass(ACTIVE);
            $("."+CURRENT, target).removeClass(CURRENT); 
        } else {
            target.addClass(ACTIVE);

            if($("."+SELECTED, target).length) { $("."+SELECTED, target).addClass(CURRENT); } 
            else { $(HEX_LIST+" li:first-child", target).addClass(CURRENT); }

            scrollTo($("."+CURRENT, target), "top", target);
        }
    };

    /**
     * Removes .current from previous element and adds it to target
     * @params {jQuery} target - Item to change to .current
     * @params {jQuery} container - The .hex-selector containing the target
     */
    var updateCurrent = function(target, container) {
        $("."+CURRENT, container).removeClass(CURRENT);
        target.addClass(CURRENT);
    }

    /**
     * Jumps up the length of the dropdown to the next item
     * @params {jQuery} currentElement - Item to jump up from
     * @params {jQuery} container - The .hex-selector containing this dropdown
     * @returns {jQuery}: The element jumped to
     */
    var pageUp = function(currentElement, container) {
        var nextPos = currentElement.position().top + currentElement.height() - container.height();
        while(currentElement.position().top > nextPos) {
            if(currentElement.prev().length) { currentElement = currentElement.prev() }
            else { break; }
        }   
        return currentElement;
    }

    /**
     * Jumps down the length of the dropdown to the next item
     * @params {jQuery} currentElement - Item to jump down from
     * @params {jQuery} container - The .hex-selector containing this dropdown
     * @returns {jQuery}: The element jumped to
     */
     var pageDown = function(currentElement, container) {
        var nextPos = currentElement.position().top - currentElement.height() + container.height();
        while(currentElement.position().top < nextPos) {
            if(currentElement.next().length) { currentElement = currentElement.next() }
            else { break; }
        }   
        return currentElement;
    }


    $(document).on('mousedown', function(e){ click = $(e.target).closest(HEX_SELECTOR); });
    $(document).on('mousemove', function(){ mouseIgnore = false; });
    $(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
        var TAB_KEY    =  9,
          ENTER_KEY  = 13,
          ESC_KEY    = 27,
          SPACE_KEY  = 32,
          PGUP_KEY   = 33,
          PGDOWN_KEY = 34,
          END_KEY    = 35,
          HOME_KEY   = 36,
          UP_KEY     = 38,
          DOWN_KEY   = 40;


    // When in a dropdown, selects current item and closes dropdown
    if(event.which == TAB_KEY) {
        var temp_hex_selector = $(HEX_SELECTOR);
        for(var i = 0; i < temp_hex_selector.length; i++){
                var selector = $(temp_hex_selector[i]);
                if(selector.hasClass(ACTIVE)) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    selectItem(selector.find("."+CURRENT), selector);
                    toggleSelector(selector);
                }
            }
    }

    // When in a dropdown, selects current item and closes dropdown
    // Otherwise, opens the dropdown
    if(event.which == ENTER_KEY) {
        var temp_hex_selection = $(HEX_SELECTION);
        for(var i = 0;  i < temp_hex_selection.length; i++) {
            if($(temp_hex_selection[i]).is(":focus")) {
                var selector = $(temp_hex_selection[i]).closest(HEX_SELECTOR);
            if(selector.hasClass(ACTIVE)){ selectItem(selector.find("."+CURRENT), selector); }
                    toggleSelector(selector);
        }
        }
    }

    // Closes an open dropdown without selecting an item
    if(event.which == ESC_KEY) {
        var temp_hex_selector = $(HEX_SELECTOR);
        for(var i = 0; i < temp_hex_selector.length; i++){
                var selector = $(temp_hex_selector[i]);
                if(selector.hasClass(ACTIVE)) { toggleSelector(selector); }
            }
    }

    // Selects current item without closing the dropdown
    if(event.which == SPACE_KEY) {
        var temp_hex_selection = $(HEX_SELECTION);
        for(var i = 0;  i < temp_hex_selection.length; i++) {
            if($(temp_hex_selection[i]).is(":focus")) {
                var selector = $(temp_hex_selection[i]).closest(HEX_SELECTOR);
            if(selector.hasClass(ACTIVE)){ selectItem(selector.find("."+CURRENT), selector); }
        }
        }
    }

    // Jumps the length of dropdown to next selection
    if(event.which == PGUP_KEY || event.which == PGDOWN_KEY) {
        mouseIgnore = true;
        var temp_hex_selection = $(HEX_SELECTION);
        for(var i = 0;  i < temp_hex_selection.length; i++) {
            if($(temp_hex_selection[i]).is(":focus")) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var selector = $(temp_hex_selection[i]).closest(HEX_SELECTOR);
                if(selector.hasClass(ACTIVE)){
                    var currentElement = selector.find("."+CURRENT);
                    if(event.which == PGUP_KEY) {
                    currentElement = pageUp(currentElement, currentElement.closest(HEX_LIST));
                    scrollTo($(currentElement, selector), "top", selector);
                } else {
                    currentElement = pageDown(currentElement, currentElement.closest(HEX_LIST));
                    scrollTo($(currentElement, selector), "bot", selector);
                }
                } else {
                    var currentElement = $(HEX_LIST+" li:first-child", selector);
                    if(selector.find("."+SELECTED).length) 
                    { 
                        currentElement = selector.find("."+SELECTED); 
                        if(event.which == PGUP_KEY) { currentElement = pageUp(currentElement, currentElement.closest(HEX_LIST)); }
                        else { currentElement = pageDown(currentElement, currentElement.closest(HEX_LIST)); }
                    }
                }
                selectItem(currentElement, selector);
            }
        }
    }

    // Jumps to first/last element of dropdown
    if(event.which == END_KEY || event.which == HOME_KEY) {
        mouseIgnore = true;
        var temp_hex_selection = $(HEX_SELECTION);
        for(var i = 0;  i < temp_hex_selection.length; i++) {
            if($(temp_hex_selection[i]).is(":focus")) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var selector = $(temp_hex_selection[i]).closest(HEX_SELECTOR);
                var currentElement = $(HEX_LIST+" li:last-child", selector);
                if(event.which == HOME_KEY) { currentElement = $(HEX_LIST+" li:first-child", selector); }
                selectItem(currentElement, selector);
                if(selector.hasClass(ACTIVE))
                {  
                    if(event.which == END_KEY) { scrollTo($(currentElement, selector), "bot", selector); }
                    else { scrollTo($(currentElement, selector), "top", selector); }
                } 
            }
        }
    }

    // Moves to next/previous item in dropdown
    if(event.which == UP_KEY || event.which == DOWN_KEY) {
        mouseIgnore = true;
        var temp_hex_selection = $(HEX_SELECTION);
        for(var i = 0;  i < temp_hex_selection.length; i++) {
            if($(temp_hex_selection[i]).is(":focus")) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var selector = $(temp_hex_selection[i]).closest(HEX_SELECTOR);
                if(selector.hasClass(ACTIVE)){
                    var currentElement = selector.find("."+CURRENT);
                    if(event.which == UP_KEY) {
                        if(currentElement.prev().length)      { currentElement = currentElement.prev(); }
                        if(currentElement.position().top < 0) { scrollTo($(currentElement, selector), "top", selector); }
                    } else {
                        if(currentElement.next().length)        { currentElement = currentElement.next(); }
                        if(currentElement.position().top > 211) { scrollTo($(currentElement, selector), "bot", selector); }
                    }
                } else {
                    var currentElement = $(HEX_LIST+" li:first-child", selector);
                    if(selector.find("."+SELECTED).length) { currentElement = selector.find("."+SELECTED); }
                    if(event.which == UP_KEY) {
                        if(currentElement.prev().length) { currentElement = currentElement.prev(); }
                    } else {
                        if(currentElement.next().length) { currentElement = currentElement.next(); }
                    }
                }
                selectItem(currentElement, selector);
            }
        }
    }

    // Tracks users input and attempts to jump to matching entry in dropdown
    // user input resets after 1s of no input
    if(event.which > 59 && event.which < 91) {
        mouseIgnore = true;
            var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
            if(currentTime - typingReset < 1000) { searchString = searchString + String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode); }
            else { searchString = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode); }
            var temp_hex_selection = $(HEX_SELECTION);
        for(var i = 0;  i < temp_hex_selection.length; i++) {
            if($(temp_hex_selection[i]).is(":focus")) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var selector = $(temp_hex_selection[i]).closest(HEX_SELECTOR);
                var currentElement = $(HEX_LIST+" li:first-child", selector);
                while(currentElement.length){
                        if(currentElement.text().toLowerCase().match("^" + searchString.toLowerCase())) {
                            selectItem(currentElement, selector);
                            if($(HEX_LIST, selector).hasClass(ACTIVE)) {
                                if(currentElement.position().top < 0)        { scrollTo($(currentElement, selector), "top", selector); }
                                else if(currentElement.position().top > 211) { scrollTo($(currentElement, selector), "bot", selector); }
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        currentElement = currentElement.next();
                    }
            }
        }
        typingReset = new Date().getTime();
    }
    });

    $(HEX_LIST+" > li").on("click", function(event) {
        var container = $(this).closest(HEX_SELECTOR)
        selectItem($(this), container);
        container.find(HEX_SELECTION).focus()
    }); 
    $(HEX_LIST+" > li").on("mouseenter", function() { mouseSelection($(this)); });
    $(HEX_LIST+" > li").on("mousemove", function()  { mouseSelection($(this)); });

    $(HEX_SELECTION).on("blur", function() {
        var container = $(this).closest(HEX_SELECTOR);
        if(container.hasClass(ACTIVE) && container[0] !== click[0]) {
            container.removeClass(ACTIVE);
        }
    });

    $(HEX_SELECTOR).on("click", function(){ toggleSelector($(this)); });

}());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help ensure your site displays well across browsers, you should validate your HTML at the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input).

It is actually very good, but there are two problems.  `<span value="null">` and `<span value="#">` are invalid - you should remove the `value` attribute.

You can validate your CSS at a [W3C validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input) too.  Other than the unknown vender extensions, it appears to be valid.

Your JavaScript looks neat and clean for the most part, but your have irregular indentation in a few places:

> ```
> for(var i = 0;  i < temp_hex_selection.length; i++) {
>     if($(temp_hex_selection[i]).is(":focus")) {
>         var selector = $(temp_hex_selection[i]).closest(HEX_SELECTOR);
>     if(selector.hasClass(ACTIVE)){ selectItem(selector.find("."+CURRENT), selector); }
> }
> }
> ```

That should be indented to easily see what is part of what, like this:

```
for(var i = 0;  i < temp_hex_selection.length; i++) {
    if($(temp_hex_selection[i]).is(":focus")) {
        var selector = $(temp_hex_selection[i]).closest(HEX_SELECTOR);
        if(selector.hasClass(ACTIVE)) {
            selectItem(selector.find("."+CURRENT), selector);
        }
    }
}
```

I would also put a space around my operators to make it easy to see the separate parts of the equations:

> ```
> scrollTo($("."+CURRENT, target), "top", target);
> ```

Becomes:

```
scrollTo($("." + CURRENT, target), "top", target);
```

Right here:

> ```
> if(event.which == UP_KEY) {
>     if(currentElement.prev().length)      { currentElement = currentElement.prev(); }
>     if(currentElement.position().top < 0) { scrollTo($(currentElement, selector), "top", selector); }
> }
> ```

I would not indent my `if` blocks like that.  I would write them like this:

```
if(event.which == UP_KEY) {
    if(currentElement.prev().length) {
        currentElement = currentElement.prev();
    }
    if(currentElement.position().top < 0) {
        scrollTo($(currentElement, selector), "top", selector);
    }
}
```